# Merge two complex arrays of objects by field in javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am grouping objects retrieved from my database in an array by a field. As I am using pagination, the new grouped array has to be merged with the previous one.

For example, if I had this array

```
const previousGroupedFood = [
  {
    type: "fruits",
    data: [{ name: "Orange", color: "orange" }, { name: "Apple", color: "red" }]
  },
  {
    type: "drinks",
    data: [ { name: "Coke Zero", calories: 0 } ]
  }    
];
```

and after fetching my database again and merging the result I get

```
const newGroupedFood = [
  {
    type: "fruits",
    data: [{ name: "Tomato", color: "red" }]
  },
  {
    type: "desserts",
    data: [ { name: "Lemon Tart", calories: 430 } ]
  }    
]
```

How can I merge both arrays using ES6? So I get this result?

```
[
  {
    type: "fruits",
    data: [{ name: "Orange", color: "orange" }, { name: "Apple", color: "red" }, { name: "Tomato", color: "red" }]
  },
  {
    type: "drinks",
    data: [{ name: "Coke Zero", calories: 0 }]
  },
  {
    type: "desserts", // No lexical order, pushing in the tail of the list
    data: [{ name: "Lemon Tart", calories: 430 }]
  }
];
```

Comment: Are the data items unique in each page or could they be duplicate? What do you want to see when there is { name: "Tomato", color: "red" } in third page for fruits?

Comment: @hurricane Unique data. I am rendering the items in a section list, in my real use case I have uris to the items and other data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can try this

```js
const previousGroupedFood = [{
    type: "fruits",
    data: [{
      name: "Orange",
      color: "orange"
    }, {
      name: "Apple",
      color: "red"
    }]
  },
  {
    type: "drinks",
    data: [{
      name: "Coke Zero",
      calories: 0
    }]
  }
];

const newGroupedFood = [{
    type: "fruits",
    data: [{
      name: "Tomato",
      color: "red"
    }]
  },
  {
    type: "desserts",
    data: [{
      name: "Lemon Tart",
      calories: 430
    }]
  }
];

newGroupedFood.forEach(item => {
  const match = previousGroupedFood.find(({type}) => type === item.type);
  if (match) {
    match.data = [...match.data,...item.data];
  } else {
    previousGroupedFood.push(item);
  }
});

console.log(previousGroupedFood);
```

Comment: Agree with this answer. To use specifically `es6` syntax you can replace the `concat` with the spread operator.

A simple example would be `[...array1, ...array2]`

Answer (score 1):

D. Seah's solution is great, but it could have a performance issue since you search in another array. I would first group the items and then return them instead of searching for new items in the existing array.

```
function mergeData(key, items) {
  const groupedData = items.reduce((prev, item) => {
    if (prev[item.type]) {
      prev[item.type] = [...prev[item.type], ...item.data]
    } else {
      prev[item.type] = item.data;
    }
    return prev;
  }, {});
  return Object.keys(groupedData).map(key => ({
    type: key,
    data: groupedData[key]
  }))
}

const previousGroupedFood = [{
    type: "fruits",
    data: [{
      name: "Orange",
      color: "orange"
    }, {
      name: "Apple",
      color: "red"
    }]
  },
  {
    type: "drinks",
    data: [{
      name: "Coke Zero",
      calories: 0
    }]
  }
];

const newGroupedFood = [{
    type: "fruits",
    data: [{
      name: "Tomato",
      color: "red"
    }]
  },
  {
    type: "desserts",
    data: [{
      name: "Lemon Tart",
      calories: 430
    }]
  }
]

console.log(mergeData('type', [...newGroupedFood, ...previousGroupedFood]));
```

Answer (score 1):

If the intent is to collect data you could have an array `foods.list` which contains the desired result and a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) `foods.refs` which holds the index for each type. Add a method `foods.addGrouped` to simplify adding the the received response.

```js
const previousGroupedFood = [{type:"fruits",data:[{name:"Orange",color:"orange"},{name:"Apple",color:"red"}]},{type:"drinks",data:[{name:"Coke Zero",calories:0}]}];
const newGroupedFood = [{type:"fruits",data:[{name:"Tomato",color:"red"}]},{type:"desserts",data:[{name:"Lemon Tart",calories:430}]}];

class Foods {
  constructor() {
    this.list = [];
    this.refs = new Map();
  }
  
  addGrouped(groups) {
    for (const { type, data } of groups) {
      if (!this.refs.has(type)) {
        this.refs.set(type, this.list.length);
        this.list.push({ type, data: [] });
      }
      this.list[this.refs.get(type)].data.push(...data);
    }
  }
}

const foods = new Foods()

console.log(foods.list);
foods.addGrouped(previousGroupedFood);
console.log(foods.list);
foods.addGrouped(newGroupedFood);
console.log(foods.list);
```

Note that `foods.list` and `foods.refs` should not be re-assigned after creation and both structures should not be mutated. Only the Foods instance should manage these structures.

If you need additional actions like removing a specific food type, add an additional method and update both structures accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an concise answer using [object-lib](https://github.com/blackflux/object-lib)

```js
// const objectLib = require('object-lib');

const { Merge } = objectLib;

const previousGroupedFood = [{ type: 'fruits', data: [{ name: 'Orange', color: 'orange' }, { name: 'Apple', color: 'red' }] }, { type: 'drinks', data: [{ name: 'Coke Zero', calories: 0 }] }];
const newGroupedFood = [{ type: 'fruits', data: [{ name: 'Tomato', color: 'red' }] }, { type: 'desserts', data: [{ name: 'Lemon Tart', calories: 430 }] }];

const merge = Merge({ '[*]': 'type' });

console.log(merge(previousGroupedFood, newGroupedFood));
/* => [
  { type: 'fruits', data: [ { name: 'Orange', color: 'orange' }, { name: 'Apple', color: 'red' }, { name: 'Tomato', color: 'red' } ] },
  { type: 'drinks', data: [ { name: 'Coke Zero', calories: 0 } ] },
  { type: 'desserts', data: [ { name: 'Lemon Tart', calories: 430 } ] }
] */
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

```html
<script src="https://bundle.run/object-lib@2.1.0"></script>
```

*Disclaimer*: I'm the author of [object-lib](https://www.npmjs.com/package/object-lib)